# ReactJS Bootstrap Navbar issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

I'm having a lot of trouble with just the Navbar, see when I import CustomNavbar into App.jsx and then when I use it in the div then I'm constantly getting an error saying 'Element ref was specified as a string (inner) but no owner was set.' However, if I try any other item such as a  tag or a

tag or anything else, I have no issues, Please help﻿

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './componenets/Home';
import About from './componenets/About';
import News from './componenets/News';
import Navbar from './componenets/CustomNavbar';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/news" component={News} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class CustomNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Link to="/">Hello</Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} componentClass={Link} to="/" >
              Home
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} componentClass={Link} to="/about" >
              About
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={3} componentClass={Link} to="/news" >
              News
            </NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `react-bootstrap` are you using?

Comment: react-bootstrap 0.32.1

Comment: If you wish to see the entire code here is the github link 
https://github.com/arunseshan/ReactWebsite

Comment: componentClass={Link}? use https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap

Comment: Still getting this error : 
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `CustomNavbar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the dependencies were not updated. Look when you install a library you have to also save it. In this instance, the mistake I did was

1. not installing using `--save` as in `npm install react-bootstrap react-router-dom --save`
2. Forgetting to `cd` to my working directory before I installed it.

Once you install the libraries using npm "*after*" being in the directory of your project and then using the `--save` attribute in the end; you will not have this issue.

To verify this all you have to do is that you check the package.json file in your project directory and make sure that all the dependencies that you intend to use in this project are listed in the dependencies object.

It was a silly mistake yet a valid one. Thanks to Brice Ayres who gave me the solution, you should probably check out his [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9nBRXEi-gthsZf8BBhp_Jw). The guy really knows what he is teaching and gives great response to his viewers.

Thanks to all those who did attempt to solve my problem.